# ProgressDialog in Fragment triggers host Activity's onPause method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-activity, onpause

So I've been doing some research in my code relating to a bug (called commit in the onPostExecute of an Async Task, sometimes throws IllegalStateException) and I am finding that when I start my Async Task from within my Fragment, and show a progress dialog, my Activity calls his onPause method, which cascades to the corresponding onPause within my Fragment. I've looked at the API and here but found no answers. Why is onPause in my activity called? The activity is not necessarily going into the background is it?

Answer (score 0):

When your activity is going to the background, the `onStop()` method is called. However, when you show a Dialog, the activity isn't at the top of your view, thus the `onPause()` method is called.

If you have something that you want to do in your `onPause()` method that shouldn't be executed when you want to show your Dialog, then you need to set up a flag and only execute that code if the flag is true:

```
@Overrides
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (myFlag) {
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

You toggle your flag when you show your Dialog and when you dismiss it.

Comment: How about if I wanted to do something before onResume. As I mentioned, I am getting an IllegalStateException due to my trying to commit a Fragment transaction in the onPostExecute of my AsyncTask. Is there any reasonable way to defer the commit until onResume?